# the_post_thumbnail not working with me

Tags: wordpress

I'm not super familiar with wordpress, but I've been working on getting my layout written as a theme so I can use the wordpress platform. For some reason I can't get the_post_thumbnail function working. 
so when use this

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100));
```

its show me this error

```
  Illegal offset type in
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled thumbnails in the functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

In your `functions.php`, you should add this in order to enable featured thumbnails:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

And then call inside your loop, or inside your `while`:

```
<?php 
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large', true);
    echo $image_url[0];  
?>
```

It will return your featured image URL and then you can echo the `$image_url[0]` wherever you want.